# autojump : favor folders that share the most parents with current directory

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, autojump

Say I have following folders hierarchies :

```
/home/kray/virtualenv/dev1/myproj/bin
/home/kray/virtualenv/dev2/myproj/bin
```

And i type in a console:

```
$ pwd                                                    
/home/kray/virtualenv/dev1/
$ autojump bin
```

can I configure autojump so that, in this case when I'm located in `dev1` dir, it always jumps to `./myproj/bin` instead of changing of virtualenv to jump to `/home/kray/virtualenv/dev2/myproj/bin`.
So can we make autojump take the context (parent folders) into account instead of solely basing its judgment on directories popularity (number of times I visited the folder in the past) ?